# Linearlayout background image

Tags: android, layout, background

I have a problem with Linearlayout background. The issue is that I am setting LinearLayout background as image. Lets say image size is 300 px height. This LinearLayout holds other views lets say rows. One row is 100 px height. The problem is that when I am adding a row to this LinearLayout, row fill only 100 px of 300 px. The question would be is it possible to strech or scale LinearLayout depending on how much it's children views take place?

The code of LinearLayout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/companies_list_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/firm_list_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: The image suppose to stretch to fill the layout automatically. I don't understand what you mean - your image is 300px and you want to stretch it to fill 100px? (do you mean shrink?). An illustration of what you want to achieve may help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear so:

First of all when you set an image as the background of a layout it is scaled to fit or cover the whole size of the layout.

Another method to do the same think is to add an imageview in your layout with `android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"`

and set its background resource to `android:scaleType:"fitXY"`

So:
1: You have set your companies_list_holder height to wrap_content so if a row is 100px height. it also has 100px height so the background is scaled to fit your 100px height layout.

2: If you had set your layout to have a 300dp height it would be scaled to fit your 300dp layout etc etc. then you could add your 100dp height child rows.

Finally i think that if you want to add multiple and unknown number of rows in a layout, the best solution is a ListView like in this example:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

and your listView would handle many thinks like scrolling etc

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the height of your inner row and then set this height as height of your LinearLayout using LayoutParams